# How to incoporate jQuery UI into ASP.NET MVC 5 project that is on an offline system?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2015

I am having some issues trying to incorporate jQuery UI into my project. I cannot use Nuget or anything else that goes to the internet, so I have downloaded the development package from the jQuery UI website, and have been trying to include the files from the download into the MVC 5 project in visual studio 2015 as follows.

1.) Created an MVC5 application in Visual Studio 2015.

2.) Built a full download on the jQuery UI website (http://jqueryui.com/download/) on a different computer with online access.

3.) Unzipped the downloaded folder and in the same location as the sample provided html (index.html) that is within this folder, I created my own html page to use some widgets to practice.

4.) Back in the offline computer, in the Content folder in the VS 2015 project, I created a folder called "css" and moved all the files from the download related to styling (i.e. the "images" folder) and all the files with css extension (including self-created ones) to here.

5.) In the Scripts folder of the VS2015 project, I created a folder called "jqueryui" and to here I moved the js files from the download, as well as the js file I created for my sample widget page.

6.) Still within the Scripts folder of the VS2015 project, I moved in the "jquery.js" file that was in the "external" folder in the unzipped download folder.

7.) Moved my sample html code into a new view cshtml I created in VS2015 called "Jqueryui.cshtml".

8.) In this view, I modified my style and script links as follows to update the paths:

In the html  tag:

```
<link href="~/Content/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/mycustom.css">
```

Within the html  tag:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jqueryui/mycustom.js"></script>
```

9.) Added code in the appropriate controller to access this view.

10.) Run the project and try to access the page in IE8, I get an error as follows in the debugger:

"Object doesn't support this property or method" 
On the following line of code (this is first of several lines of code that show this error):

( "#tabsuseradmin" ).tabs();

and then past the breakpoint, I get the page back with no styling or jQuery UI widgets whatsoever. The result is similar in the latest Firefox I downloaded from cnet.com today.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in getting jQuery UI running in a VS2015 MVC 5 project that is not connected to the internet. I believe I have covered all my steps in my attempt, and I am stuck on what to do now. The sample I created on my computer that is online works fine 
(I know it's irreleavant that it is online in the context of the sample page I created, but this makes me believe I am messing up the path information when I moved the files to the different directory structure of the VS 2015 project (step 8)).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you confirm all the links are pointing to the correct script by viewing the source in a browser and clicking on them?

Comment: `I get the page back with no styling or jQuery UI widgets whatsoever` - probably because you haven't included the MIME type `type="text/css"` in your `<link>` element. For the record, it would be easier to maintain your application if you include the attributes in the same order on each `<link>` so you can spot issues like this more easily.

Comment: `I cannot use Nuget or anything else that goes to the internet` - you *can* use NuGet, since this download happens on your development computer, not on the web server. It is almost *exactly* the same process you are using with the download.

Comment: @D.Mac for some reason, clicking on the links resulted in no response whatsoever. However, I resolved the issue and have posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the maintenance tip @NightOwl888. I fixed that and looked a bit more into Nuget, and was able to download the package and transfer it to my offline computer and install it from Visual Studio there, and then followed http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/a-jquery-ui-based-date-picker-for-asp.net-mvc-5.html to set up jQuery UI.